# Expectation of a random variable over the variable's conditional value.

Tags: statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ is a binary variable. $T$ is a continuous variable which is a function of $X$.

What will be the following two expectation:

$(1)$ $\mathbb E_X[P(T\le t\mid X=0)]$, and

$(2)$ $\mathbb E_X[T\mid X=0]$ ?

What I am trying to ask is that: If we take expectation on random variable $X$, Will the expectation work on conditional $X=0$? Or, conditional $X$ is always a constant though the expectation is over $X$?

Will $(1)$ $\mathbb E_X[P(T\le t \mid X=0)]=P(T\le t\mid X=0)$? or $\mathbb E_X[P(T\le t \mid X=0)]$ become unconditional on $X$?

Comment: The subscript $X$ on your expectation operator doesn't mean anything and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Given the oddness of the language of the question, I wonder whether you might have meant that the probability distribution of $T$ depends on whether $X=0$ or $X=1$, rather than that $T$ is simply a function of $X$ (which makes the whole problem trivial).

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not asking "the probability distribution of T depends on whether $X=0$ or $X=1$". Rather just: is $E_X[T\times P(T<t|X=0)]= P(T<t|X=0)\times E_X[T]$? that is, is $P(T<t|X=0)$ constant with the expectation operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $X=0$, $(T\mid X=0)$ is no more function of $X$. So $\mathbb E_X[P(T\leq t \mid X=0)] = P(T\leq t\mid X=0)$ and $\mathbb E_X[T\mid X=0]= (T\mid X=0)$, (which is putting $X=0$ in $T$).

Comment: What in the world do you mean by $\cdots=(T\mid X=0)$?  Is the expression $(T\mid X=0)$ supposed to refer to something in particular?

Comment: As I said in the answer, it means T evaluated at X=0